# How do I create a paper curl using CSS3 and Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap's table.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Body content Body content Body content Body content Body content Body content Body content Body content Body content Body content </tr></td>
</table>
```

I want to apply a simple css class to this table to make it "curl" like a paper.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Use an image. That's pretty much the _only_ way you can do it

Comment: Do you have an example on how exactly it should look like?

Comment: Just like a paper pinned to a board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

http://www.red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/css3-box-shadow.html

That is about the closest you can get without using an image.